# how to connect jboss eap 7 to webspshere mq

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to `websphere mq` (locally installed) queue manager from `Jboss eap 7`. I have configured the properties required in `standalone-full.xml` file. but when U try to connect it fails, see the log below:

```
11:22:41,517 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: java:/jms/QueueFactory: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail. See the linked exception for details of the failure.
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:169)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:135)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.ConnectionBuilder.createConnection(ConnectionBuilder.java:225)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:579)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionImpl.<init>(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:173)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1320)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.fillTo(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1136)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'QM1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
```

Comment: What version of MQ are you at on the queue manager?  Are the jar files you reference from the same queue manager?  In the install location of the MQ Server software you will find a directory called qmgrs/<name of the queue manager>/errors with a file called AMQERR01.LOG this will have information on why the queue manager rejected your connection.  Please review this and let us know what the reason is.  This along with the MQ version will help to make some suggestions.

Comment: Thank you JoshMc for your reply. I found that the restrictions to connect the queue manger is not sharable. after changing that I am getting different issue. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'it00EventConnectionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl] available at JNDI location [it00EventQueueFactory] is not assignable to [javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory]

Comment: Please update (edit) the question and include the new details, you can not format in a comment.